# Dealing with a poorly designed "variable column" table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am dealing with a poorly designed table, somewhat like this

```
create table (
   entity_key  integer,
   tag1        varchar(10),
   tag2        varchar(10),
   tag3        varchar(10),
   ...
   tag25       varchar(10)
);
```

An entity can have 0 or more tags indicated by the number of non-null columns. Tags are all the same type, and there should be a seperate "tags" table to which we can join the primary entities.

However, I'm stuck with this (quite large) table.

I want to run a query that gives me the distinct tags and a count of each.

If we had the normed "tags" table we could simply write

```
select tag, count(tag) from tags group by tag;
```

However, I haven't yet come up with a good approach for this query given the current table structure.

Answer (score 5):

You can this by using an array and the unnest:

```
select x.tag, count(*)
from tags
    cross join lateral unnest(array[tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6, tag7, ...]) as x(tag)
where x.tag is not null --<< git rid of any empty tags
group by x.tag;
```

This will group by the *contents* of the tag columns unlike Prdp's answer which groups by the "*position*" in the column list.

For this sample data:

```
insert into tags (entity_key, tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5)
values
(1, 'sql', 'dbms', null, null, null),
(2, 'sql', 'dbms', null, null, 'dml'),
(3, 'sql', null, null, 'ddl', null);
```

This will return this:

```
tag  | count
-----+------
dml  |     1
ddl  |     1
sql  |     3
dbms |     2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can *unpivot* the data and do the `count`

```
select tag,count(data)
from
(
select tag1 as data,'tag1' as tag
from yourtable
Union All
select tag2,'tag2' as tag
from yourtable
Union All
..
select tag25,'tag25' as tag
from yourtable
) A
Group by tag
```

If postgresql supports `Unpivot` operator then you can use that